# VBA Paste Column starting at row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy all columns from one workbook sheet and paste to another workbook sheet but pasting all columns starting at Row A8

I've got the code working to copy and paste from one workbook sheet to another, I just can't figure out the code to add to paste the columns starting at row A8.

This is what I have so far:

```
Set Data = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Technical Audit.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways)
Worksheets("Raw Data").Select

Set SourceImageColumn = Workbooks("Audit Dashboard.xlsm").Worksheets("Raw Image Data").Columns("A:D")
Set TargetImageColumn = Workbooks("Technical Audit.xlsm").Worksheets("Images").Columns("A:D")

SourceImageColumn.Copy Destination:=TargetImageColumn

Data.Save
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391994/how-to-copy-the-whole-column-to-another-column-starting-from-a-certain-row or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359107/how-to-specify-start-row-for-a-copy-column-vba

Comment: It's just because I'm copying data from one workbook to another, The above code is the only one I've got working and I don't know how to use the above examples whilst still mainting the copy and paste between workbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** Updated the code **
This method will work if you have both workbooks open. I couldn't figure out if you have this or not.

```
Sub macro3()
Dim iRow        As Long
Dim lastRow     As Long
Dim nextRow     As Long
Dim wksSource   As Worksheet
Dim wksTarget   As Worksheet

Set wksSource = Workbooks("Audit Dashboard.xlsm").Worksheets("Raw Image Data")
Set wksTarget = Workbooks("Technical Audit.xlsm").Worksheets("Images")

lastRow = wksSource.Range("A" & wksSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

nextRow = 8

With wksSource
    For iRow = 1 To lastRow
        .Range(.Cells(iRow, 1), .Cells(iRow, 4)).Copy wksTarget.Cells(nextRow, 1)
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
    Next iRow
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Bud, thanks for your response. 

It's the destination worksheet (Images) I need to paste starting at A8. All of the columns in (Raw Image Data) can be copied from the first row. 

I tried to swap the code around but it didn't work, any thoughts?

Comment: `  
    Dim sourceImageColumn As Range, targetImageColumn As Range

    Set sourceImageColumn = Workbooks("Audit Dashboard.xlsm").Worksheets("Raw Image Data").Columns("A:D")
    Set targetImageColumn = Workbooks("Technical Audit.xlsm").Worksheets("Images").Range("A8:D" & Sheets("Images").Cells(Sheets("Images").Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    sourceImageColumn.Copy Destination:=targetImageColumn`

Comment: Let me have a look :-)

Comment: You sir are the definition of a Legend. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Just be aware that you need both workbooks open.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set wsCore = Workbooks("Audit Dashboard.xlsm").Worksheets("Raw Image Data")
Set wsData = Workbooks("Technical Audit.xlsm").Worksheets("Images")

With Intersect(wsCore.Columns("A:D"), wsCore.UsedRange)
    .Columns("A").Copy Destination:=wsData.Range("A8")
    .Columns("B").Copy Destination:=wsData.Range("B8")
    .Columns("C").Copy Destination:=wsData.Range("C8")
    .Columns("D").Copy Destination:=wsData.Range("D8")
End With
```

A modified answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/29359212/1544886

Will copy from `wsCore` columns A:D, and paste into `wsData` starting at A8:D8